# Smashing the stack: overflow

Tags: c++, c, stack, overflow

I've just read *Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit* (http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html) and want to explore more. Then I found this code here: https://github.com/yangsu/Stack-Smashing

I understand the principles stated here quite clearly, and I followed the steps closely, but got some error. I opened 2 terminals.

In the first terminal: (The "Segmentation fault" line appeared after typing the "cat" line in the other terminal)

```
$ sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0
$ gcc -z execstack -fno-stack-protector webserver.c -o server
$ ./server 5000
Segmentation fault.  Shutting down peacefully, then rebooting.
$
```

In the second terminal,

```
$ g++ generate.cpp -o generate
$ ./generate
$ cat data.dat | nc 127.0.0.1 5000
$
```

Was the error caused by wrong formats or paramaters of the "cat" line? Or any other causes?

Also, as written in the function *sigsegv*, the server should restart after 2 sec. But in my execution here it didn't. Why is this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you checked that the server actually is not running in the background?

Comment: Though I couldn't find an answer for you. I just loved that link you posted. Thank you. :)

Comment: I used ps to check and it wasn't there...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry... but do you have any idea what's going on with the segmentation fault?

Comment: What OS? Something that comes to mind is [address space randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Linux), which is designed to make programs with overflows crash rather than allow arbitrary code execution. Linux has had it enabled by default since 2.6.12 and many BSD flavors long before that.

Comment: Gah, just saw the `sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0`; never mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learning to smash the stack starts with paying attention to the smallest details.
A successful exploit and a simple process crash are almost exactly the same. You must find the fine difference and change the exploit.

Start by debugging the crashed program.
Why exactly did it crash? What was written where on the stack?
Did it crash because the return address was modified (in this case you're half way there), or for some other reason?

If you can't answer these questions, then even if you get things working, you will learn nothing.

Comment: Hi ugoren, thank you for your comments. I've read through the code and I think program will be crashed because the line *strncpy(filename, start, len);* in the function *handle* can always overwrite its return address. My confusion lies in that I'm very unfamiliar with signals, so I haven't figured out where the signal SIGSEGV comes from...

Comment: The signal basically says that bad memory was accessed. You need to use the debugger to figure out exactly what bad memory was accessed, in what way (read/write/execute) and by which instruction.